# Uncaught ReferenceError: execute is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used execute function on click of execute button.But while clicking on this button I am getting `"Uncaught ReferenceError: execute is not defined"` error in my console. onclickng I am creating input box and button.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en=US">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <title>Create Course</title>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>

                <input id="textbox" type="text" /><br><br>
<!-- here i declare function-->      <button id="numFiles" onclick="execute()">execute</button><br>   <!-- in console there are showing me error here-->
                <form  method = "POST">

                    <p id="status"></p>
            </form>

        <script>

    here i used-- function execute()
        { 
            var NumFiles = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
            var i=1;
            while(NumFiles>0)
            {
                var input = document.createElement("Input");
                input.type = "text";
                input.id = i;
                var exp = document.body;
                exp.appendChild(input);
                var br = document.createElement("br");
                document.body.appendChild(br);
                var br1 = document.createElement("br");
                document.body.appendChild(br1);
                NumFiles = NumFiles-1;
                i=i+1;
            }

            var x = document.createElement("INPUT");

            x.setAttribute("type", "button");
            x.setAttribute("id","sub");

        }
              </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I tried with change different name but still getting same error. 
 any idea about this kind of error??

Comment: Works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/9h11ytuL/

Comment: That's strange... it should be working... Are you sure that your page is not caching?

Comment: but for me it still showing  same error

Comment: `here i used-- function execute()`: the `here i used--`, is this in your code? the whole code you posted is working fine on my browser

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your script in the head tag, instead of body.
Also, try to force a refresh to clean the Cache.
Windows - Ctrl+F5 
Mac - Command+shift+R